# Can't remove Docker Volume

Tags: docker, debian, volume, docker-volume, convoy

I trying to remove a docker volume but i've go "It is still mounted" error.. (i use the Convoy plugin)

I don't have any docker container on the server, i removed all of theme,
`docker ps -a CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES`

This is my "blocked" volume
`docker volume ls DRIVER    VOLUME NAME convoy    test convoy    test2`

when i tried to remove it :
 `docker volume rm test test2 Error response from daemon: remove test: Cannot delete volume test. It is still mounted Error response from daemon: remove test2: Cannot delete volume test2. It is still mounted`
(even with force option)

the inspect command return this:
 `docker volume inspect test [ { "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z", "Driver": "convoy", "Labels": null, "Mountpoint": "/mnt/docker/volumes/test", "Name": "test", "Options": null, "Scope": "local" } ]`

at the mount point i've got the folder, but it is not mounted, if i want to umount, i've got "umount: /mnt/docker/volumes/test: not mounted."

I already tried all prune command, remove command, restart, armagedon function (from other question on SO) but nothing has worked..

somebody have a clue on this ?

Comment: have you tried force deleting the volume?  `docker volume rm -f <volume>`

Comment: Thanks for the response but it's not work.. i've got the same error

Comment: what about this `convoy delete <volume>` or inspect with `convoy inspect <volume>` ,  i am kind sure that the problem is convoy maybe deleting the plugin will help you , just be careful that you don't have other containers based on that volume plugin

Comment: the convoy command return the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

use this commnad to delete stoped container and then delete your volume
**docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)**

Comment: Thanks for the response, i don't have any docker running on the server, just two residual volume from previous test..

Comment: have you try to restart your os or update your docker version ?

Comment: hello, yes, i tried lot of reboot, i upgrade docker , the system , all the compenent of docker but nothing change